# user input(string) writing to a file until the user gives an empty line

Tags: c

I am writing the user inputs(strings) to a file. But I want to end the program when the user press enter without entering any string.
for a example
Input:

hello how
are you!

end the program.

I tried to do that in this way. But it do not stops when the user enters nothing.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


int main(void)
{

    char buffer[1000];

    char sent[1000];
    FILE* ifp = fopen("text.txt", "w");


        while (sscanf(buffer,"%s",sent) == 1) {

        fprintf(ifp,"%s",buffer);

       }
    fclose(ifp);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there some code missing from your example? This example does not actually ask the user for any input.
Also, you should really check the return value from `fopen()` - as in `if (!ifp) { perror("fopen"); exit(1); }`.

Comment: Anyway ... If you are trying to read strings (character arrays), it might be better to use `fgets()` instead of `sscanf()`. Bear in mind that you will have to strip the newline character.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are doing:

```
while (sscanf(buffer,"%s",sent) == 1) {
```

but nowhere filling any contents in `buffer`.
As suggested by David Collins, its better to user `fgets()` instead of `sscanf()`. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char input[LINE_MAX];
    FILE *ifp = fopen("text.txt", "w");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(input, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (input[0] == '\n')
            break;

        fprintf (ifp, "%s", input);
    }

    fclose (ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code by :

```
char *buffer;

if ((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000)) == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
memset(buffer, 0, 1000);

while (read(0, buffer, 1000) != 0) {
    if (strcmp(buffer, "\n") == 0)
       break;
    fprintf(ifp,"%s",buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, 1000);
 }
```

And alert the user that he cannont write messages with more than 1000 characters